# assigning IDs to several child elements, jQuery

Tags: jquery

So. I gotta creat a div, and inside some elements, and than giving them some IDs.

```
var $mainDiv = $("#wrapper").append("<div></div>");
    $mainDiv.attr('id', 'main-div'); 
var $dismissButton = $mainDiv.append("<button>X</button>");
    $dismissButton.attr('id', 'dismissButton');
```

the problem starts when i give the dismissbutton it's id. The result shows that $maindiv gets the id "dismissbutton". it reaplaces the id of maindiv with other id i might mention later on.

i've figued out some of the problem but yet to find a solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your html as well.

Comment: the html is empty. there is only a css file which selects the futured id's and styles them.

the outcome should be this:
<div id="main-div">
        <button id="dismissButton">X</button>
</div>

Comment: You seem to say there is no `#wrapper` element? So what, precisely, do you expect to happen when you try and append content to a non-existent element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
var $dismissButton = $mainDiv.append("<button>X</button>");
```

The append function does not return a jQuery object representing the appended HTML. It will return the `$mainDiv` jQuery object. This is why you are seeing the behaviour you have mentioned.

Instead create the dismiss button as a jQuery object and append it to the main div. Then give it an ID.

```
var $dismissButton = $("<button>X</button>").appendTo($mainDiv);

$dismissButton.attr('id', 'dismissButton');
```

OR give it the ID when you create it

```
var $dismissButton = $("<button>X</button>", { 
    id : "dismissButton" 
}).appendTo($mainDiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating the `<div>` element, with its required properties, and then using `appendTo()` to insert into the document:

```
$('<div />', {
    'id' : 'main-div'
}).appendTo('#wrapper');
```

With this approach you're directly assigning the `id` (of `'main-div'`) to the created element (other element-types can be created and other properties can, of course, be similarly assigned), and then appending that element to the `#wrapper` element.

It's worth pointing out that, in your own approach, the problem is that `append()` returns the element to which the appended content was appended, *not* the appended content itself. So, to continue your own approach you could simply use `find()`:

```
// finds all <div> descendants of the '#wrapper' element:
var $mainDiv = $("#wrapper").append("<div></div>").find('div').attr('id', 'main-div');
```

Or:

```
// finds only the direct descendants (the children)
// of the '#wrapper' element:
var $mainDiv = $("#wrapper").append("<div></div>").children('div').attr('id', 'main-div');
```

This, of course, will assign the same `id` to *all* the `<div>` elements found, which results in invalid HTML; so you'd have to specify *which* `<div>`:

```
var $mainDiv = $("#wrapper").append("<div></div>").children('div').last().attr('id', 'main-div');
```

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).

Comment: Fastest fingers first! :-) Beat me to the best answer.

Comment: I can only say I've had practice :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
$("#wrapper").append(
    $("<div>").attr("id", "main-div")
        .append(
            $("<button>")
               .text("X")
               .attr("id", "dismissButton")));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0yabvnz2/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your script is that in this line:

```
var $dismissButton = $mainDiv.append("<button>X</button>");
```

you assign $mainDiv to the $dismissButton.
You need to either use something like this:

```
$mainDiv.append("<button id='dismissButton'>X</button>");
```

or something like this:

```
$mainDiv.append("<button id='dismissButton'>X</button>");
$mainDiv.children('button').attr('id', 'dismissButton');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
var $mainDiv = $("<div>Main Div</div>");
  $mainDiv.attr('id', 'main-div');
var $dismissButton = $("<button>X</button>");
  $dismissButton.attr('id', 'dismissButton'); 
  $mainDiv.append($dismissButton);

$('#wrapper').append($mainDiv);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/88qxa7vy/